# Automating Salesforce to Salesforce with Apex

Tags: apex, trigger, salesforce2salesforce

I came across Rakesh' Salesforce-to-Salesforce sharing through Flow & Process.  But I am curious on how to get it down with Apex.

I was able to create this trigger and save it:

```
trigger AutoShareOpportunity on Opportunity (after insert) {

    List<PartnerNetworkConnection> connMap = new List<PartnerNetworkConnection>(
    [select Id, ConnectionStatus, ConnectionName from PartnerNetworkConnection
        where ConnectionStatus = 'Accepted']
);
for(PartnerNetworkConnection network : connMap) {    
     PartnerNetworkRecordConnection newrecord = new PartnerNetworkRecordConnection();

    newrecord.ConnectionId = network.Id;
    newrecord.LocalRecordId =OpportunityId;  
    newrecord.RelatedRecords = 'Contact,Opportunity,Orders__c';
    newrecord.SendClosedTasks = true;
    newrecord.SendOpenTasks = true;
    newrecord.SendEmails = true;   

    insert newrecord;   
}
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Apex trigger AutoShareOpportunity caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: AutoShareOpportunity: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, Insufficient access on the entity.: []: Trigger.AutoShareOpportunity: line 19, column 1

Comment: You need not perform DML operation in for loop.it will cause DML Exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can't share a record before it's been inserted and has an Id. Your line `newrecord.LocalRecordId = tid;` wouldn't appear to have an Id on before insert. From the [Object Reference on PartnerNetworkConnection](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_partnernetworkrecordconnection.htm?search_text=partnernetworkconnection), note the following:

> - To share a record, use the following fields: LocalRecordID and ConnectionId
> - To share a child of a parent record, use the following fields: LocalRecordID, ConnectionId, and ParentRecordID
> - To share a child of a parent record and its child records, use the following fields: LocalRecordID, ConnectionId, ParentRecordID, and RelatedRecords

Here's some sample sharing code from the Object Reference that could be used within your trigger that once you modified it for AfterInsert, instead of BeforeInsert:

```
List<PartnerNetworkConnection)> connMap = new List<PartnerNetworkConnection>(
    [select Id, ConnectionStatus, ConnectionName from PartnerNetworkConnection
        where ConnectionStatus = 'Accepted']
);
for(PartnerNetworkConnection network : connMap) {    
     PartnerNetworkRecordConnection newrecord = new PartnerNetworkRecordConnection();

    newrecord.ConnectionId = network.Id;
    newrecord.LocalRecordId = accountId;  
    newrecord.RelatedRecords = 'Contact,Opportunity,Orders__c';
    newrecord.SendClosedTasks = true;
    newrecord.SendOpenTasks = true;
    newrecord.SendEmails = true;   

    insert newrecord;   
}
```

Comment: You could have taken the `INSERT` statement out of for loop.

Comment: @Reshma As stated in my answer, the code above was copied verbatim from the documentation. Removing insert wouldn't solve the issue he's having. The above is a query for loop and is properly bulkified. The reality is that the LocalRecordId is NULL because it hasn't yet been inserted. The cross-object reference for sharing can't be created without it.

Comment: @crmprogdev thank you!
I updated the code like you said, but now I am getting an error: Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: OpportunityId at line 11 column 30

Comment: `OpportunityId` will be the Id of the opportunity record in trigger.new. You'll need to wrap `for(PartnerNetworkConnection network : connMap) {` inside a for loop of `for(Opportunity o:trigger.new){`. You'll likely also need to query for all the related related records for the opportunities before entering that loop.